# MVC, Jquery and Ajax - JSON with null parameters in controller

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with passing object with properties into controller.
Both are always null.
In console.log passed data looks fine. Where I made a mistake?
I looked into other solutions and nothing pushed me to the correct way...

C#, MVC5, Jquery 2.1.1

Controller:

```
public class Position  
{  
string intnew { get; set; }  
string intlast { get; set; }  
}
```

Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult change(Position position)
    {
    return Json(new { result = "" });
    }
```

And View:

```
var pos = new Object;
pos.intnew = '22';
pos.intlast = '11';

$.ajax({
url: '/szkolenia/change',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
datatype: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify({ position: pos }),
type: "POST",
success: function (_infoLogs) {
console.log(JSON.stringify({ position: pos }));
}
});
```

Comment: Because your properties are not `public`

Comment: Jesus.... Thank You very much!!!!

Comment: What Spehen Muecke said + [FromBody] Position position, I think

Comment: @WhoMightThisOneBe, `[FromBody]` is web-api, not mvc

Comment: [FromBody] just for API as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Your view model `Properties` must be `Public`!

```
public class Position  
{  
  public string intnew { get; set; }  
  public string intlast { get; set; }  
}
```

I suggest the first word of the `Properties` be uppercase.